# WindowManagerBadTokenException error on dismiss login modal on Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I am working with Xamarin, I am trying to login using `Xamarin.Auth`, that works correct, but when my log is successfully and I have to close the modal I am getting this error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@a60f6df is not valid; is your activity running?

This is the code that I am using when the login succeed:

```
auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) => {
    if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        App.SaveToken(eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"]);
        App.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();
    }
    else
    {
        // The user cancelled
    }
}
```

And this is the code in the `app.cs` to close the modal:

```
get
{
    return new Action(() => {

        _NavPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
   });
}
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, not now, I have found the last year, 
if someone had o will have the same issue, bellow you can find the solution, 
the reason was because some when something I got a error, the app was not able to handle, then you only have to add a *try* in this case like the bellow code.

```
     try
        {
            auth.Completed += domplete_facebook;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
```

hope this helps someone, 
regards